# How can I return dynamic response in my django application?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

I have a dynamic Django web application. Which takes CSV files as input and process and outputs the processed CSV. Sometimes it takes a huge amount of time to process the data. So when I use it on Heroku or somewhere else, I get request timeouts. Also, I want to show the status of processed files where after each iteration of processed files, the value is returned to the browser.
views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
    file = request.FILES["myFile"]
    csv1 = pd.read_csv(file)
    urllist = csv1["urls"]
    itemind = 0
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="InventoryCheck.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    max = len(urllist)
    for i in range(0, len(urllist)):
        try:
            if itemind == max:
                break
            s = get_page(urllist[i],writer)
            data, flag = gdd(s, 0)
            write_csv(data, urllist[i], writer)
            itemind += 1
            #I want to return dynamic value from here
        except:
            pass
    return response

else:
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question right now is a bit vague and isn't asking clear questions and you're unlikely to get positive responses. To get better responses, you might want to reduce the scope of your question to a single issue, and show your code that reflects the problem.

Comment: Modified thanks. If this still has issues, let me know.

Comment: The behavior you're asking for is going to require either very, very old-school periodic refreshes on the client to update the status or JS integration to use background polling or a websocket to update the page. That's going to be a fair amount of work, including plenty of view work (and server config if you're going to go for websockets), which is dependent on your existing architecture.